# What is the role of scrum master in minimizing the impact of a team member leaving the team?

Tags: scrum

As a Scrum Master, how does one plan to minimize the impact of the sprint deliverables/to the team when a team member is leaving?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about software engineering.

Comment: Sprints are supposed to be short (i.e. weeks) while notice periods are typically measured in months. Unless the person leaving is telling the team at the last minute, I'd have thought this situation is rare unless we're talking about contractors where the notice period is shorter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

When a person leaves a team, several things happen - the team's capacity for doing work decreases, some knowledge is no longer (as readily) accessible, the team's morale may decrease. There are opportunities for the Scrum Master to help coach the team through the period of transition, depending on how much notice the team has prior to the departure.

One of the ways that the Scrum Master serves the whole Scrum Team is by helping to remove impediments. Making sure that the team sets aside time for transferring knowledge can be one way to mitigate impediments after the person's departure. The Scrum Master may also have to work with the Product Owner on effectively managing the backlog and stakeholder collaboration to account for changes in the team's capacity.

As the team adjusts its way of working, the Scrum Master can help the team understand their skills and potential knowledge gaps that would get in the way of a cross-functional team. If there are any barriers to getting the needed knowledge and skills back on the team, the Scrum Master can work with the key stakeholders to make sure the team has what they need to be effective.

After the departure, the Scrum Master can facilitate the retrospectives and provide other coaching to make sure the team stays as positive and productive as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**As a Scrum Master**:

1. You see if the development team is self-organising their response to the team member leaving. If they are, you resolve any impediments they raise. If they aren't, you suggest that they need to be.
2. You explain in your reporting why the team have reduced their estimated velocity.

The above assumes you are living the Scrum dream; if you're doing "Scrum-but" where the Scrum Master is also acting as a traditional engineering manager or similar, that's a different question.